# GraalVM native-image building - ARM64

Tags: docker, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to build a Docker image in my Mac M1....

When I try to run my Image I am getting "exec format error" which as I understand a cross platform native image problem but as far as I can see I build the native-image with an arm64 GraalVM.

```
[1/7] Initializing...                                                                                    
(6,5s @ 0,23GB)
Version info: 'GraalVM 22.3.0 Java 17 CE'
Java version info: '17.0.5+8-jvmci-22.3-b08'
C compiler: cc (apple, arm64, 14.0.0)
Garbage collector: Serial GC
1 user-specific feature(s)
```

And I used a base image from alpine:arm64

https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/alpine/3.17.0/images/sha256-af06af3514c44a964d3b905b498cf6493db8f1cde7c10e078213a89c87308ba0?context=explore

and

```
uname -a
```

confirms that is an arm64 based linux.

```
Linux 5e6ec3a5a46e 5.15.64-0-virt #1-Alpine SMP Mon, 05 Sep 2022 08:02:49 +0000 aarch64 Linux
```

and

```
docker image inspect
```

reports

```
"Architecture": "arm64",
"Os": "linux",
"Size": 80206330,
"VirtualSize": 80206330,
```

it is an arm64/linux is.

What is going on here?

Comment: Is your native image a Mac or Linux binary? Mac binaries won't run inside Linux containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@peterz answer is absolutely correct, my assumption that MacOS is Unix/Linux based was false.

When I did a cross platform native-image Generation for alpine, this error disappeared.